# Share data from a controller to partial footer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In my app, i divided the folders in my view by:

```
"posts"
"pages"
"partials"
layout.blade.php
```

In my folder partials i have blade files, like nav.blade.php and footer.blade.php. In my folder "pages", i have files like home.blade.php and some other internal pages.
But now i need to pass a viable from a controller to my footer, since is needed to be shared in all views.
How i pass the variable from my PagesController that manages blade files inside the folder "pages" in the footer?

Example routeS:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@getHome');
Route::get('/registar', 'AuthenticationController@getRegistration');
Route::post('/post/comment', 'CommentController@store');
Route::get('/login', 'AuthenticationController@getLogin');
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to share some data every time particular view is called? If that so, you can do this:

```
/* App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php
** Edit the boot function, (dont forget to include View facade) */

public function boot(){
   View::composer('path_to_view', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('variable', $variable); // you can pass array here aswell
    });
}
```

Other way to do this (if you are extending the footer layout from the view you are accessing), is to pass data when you extend the layout, like this:

```
@extends('footer', ['data' => $data])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share same variable in multipe view from providers. you can also try to this

```
public function boot()
{
        //set view path in array
        View::composer(['path_to_view1', 'path_to_view2'], function ($view) {
            $view->with('variableName', $variableName);
        });

}
```